# Is this a three-tier architecture?

Tags: java, spring, jakarta-ee

The application we are evaluating is a web application built using spring and spring mvc with oracle database.

> Every click on the browser ends in a database call.
>
> Most of the business logic is in database procedures.

- How do I convince my management that this not a three tier application?
- How do I convince my management that this is not a Service Oriented Architecture?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, you have three tiers -

- Database (Oracle 3g)
- Middle ware integration (Spring)
- UI (Spring MVC)

So technically your management is correct, at least for the number of tiers in the application. You can easily make the argument that they are not following best practices, SQL is a horrible language to be doing business validations in.

On your second point, its impossible to tell if this is a SOA compliant application, though I bet my first born its not. SOA is pretty complicated, and you ask 10 people what it is you will get 15 answers. But based off your description I would say the system fails the SOA test in the areas of discoverability, composability, autonomy, abstraction, and loose coupling. And depending on how you look at it, service contract as well.

Here's a question for you though, what does your organization think it needs SOA for?

Comment: Yes having spring and spring-mvc allows for three layers. But since every call ends up in a database call it seems to me that middle layer is performing a proxy function. Effectively we a looking at UI layer -> proxy layer [business layer,data access] -> database oracle11g. Does this still qualify for a 3 tire application?  Wrt SOA I agree that there are multiple definitions around.

Comment: You still have multiple tiers, but the middle integration tier is just being *severly* underutilized. It's a thin line with these tiers especially when using a UI architecture that can effectively support middleware integration. Before J2EE and Spring we were embedding all our middleware logic in controller servlets. Odd huh? But yea, I think you can make the argument to your management that your middleware tier is effectively overhead, since its being so badly underutilized.

Answer (score 2):

From information that you provided it does not follow whether it is three tier or service oriented.

3 Tier usually means UI layer/Service Layer/Database layer. Each has it's own responsibilities. Service oriented architecture, often means that you have separate deployable services to perform different functions in the system. Your statements alone don't confirm or deny either definition.

Answer (score 2):

What you seem to have is more of a violation of the MVC pattern than of the multi-tier pattern.  In a typical MVC application the business logic belongs in controller code and not database procedures.  However, a three-tier application is only generally required to have three tiers, an interface tier, a business tier, and a persistence tier.  And technically they have that.  So I think maybe you should argue that they haven't followed MVC properly, and that at best they have a poorly implemented three-tier application.

You also haven't provided enough details to prove that it's not using a Service-Oriented Architecture (though if it is, I would be surprised).  SOA has to do with how the logical components that comprise the business logic are coupled.  If they are loosely coupled things that can be brought up and down and swapped out for different provider implementations then they would have a SOA.  If there is tight coupling such that the logical components cannot be easily separated from one another without causing major breakages, then they do not.

If they have most of their business logic residing in database procedures, then they *probably* do not have a SOA, but you never know.  The rest of their business logic may indeed follow this pattern.

Comment: I have been too harsh on assessment of three tier architecture. Now I stand corrected. Any application which has proper place holders for UI-BL-Persistance qualify for a three tire application. If there are too many database calls it indicates poor implementation. Wrt SOA i agree that there isn't enough information available. All responses get my vote and as a rule i get to select only one.